# Caddy V2 IP whitelist

Tags: linux, caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to implement IP whitelist on my Caddy v2 configuration. Something equivalent to NGINX configuration like:

```
allow 1.1.1.1;
allow 8.8.8.8;
deny all;
```

My current Caddy configuration pretty straight forward:

```
my.website.com {
        reverse_proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000 {   
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like this in caddy v2:

```
my.domain.com {
    @teammember {
        remote_ip forwarded 183.77.5.126 113.73.5.126
    }
    handle @teammember {
        reverse_proxy /* localhost:8081
    }
    respond "<h1>You are attempting to access protected resources!</h1>" 403
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not saying qed's answer is wrong, however I couldn't get it to work in my case (possibly due to using import templates inside a handle?)...

My solution was... Old config:

```
private.example.com {
  import my_template argument_1 /path/to/example/argument2
}
```

This changed to:

```
private.example.com {
  @blocked not remote_ip 1.2.3.4
  respond @blocked "<h1>Access Denied</h1>" 403
  import my_template argument_1 /path/to/example/argument2
}
```

Simply adding those two lines allows my site to be accessed on that IP. A test curl from a different IP returned the 403 error.

This is done on Caddy 2.4.6

Comment: Is there a way to wildcard remote_ip? i.e. 192.168.1.* ?

Comment: Yup - https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers#remote-ip - you can use CIDR ranges. You probably want something like `192.168.1.1/24` (according to https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr)

Comment: You can also use `abort @blocked` to prevent attacks.

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure it is possible directly in Caddy, but you can add a middleware/plugin to do this.

Here is the link you can get it : https://github.com/pyed/ipfilter

According to the doc of this middleware, to you want to allow only the 2 IPs you wrote, you should probably do something like this :

```
my.website.com {
    reverse_proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000

    ipfilter / {
        rule allow
        ip 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
        blockpage notauthorized.html
    }
}
```

I also think if want to block every requests, not just the `/`, you have to write `ipfilter /*` instead of `ipfilter /`.

Comment: The question is about Caddy V2, this middleware is for Caddy V1.